# Алгоритм по поиску максимального произведения трех чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм

Надо найти максимальное произведение трех чисел из массива. Я написал код, но на одном из этапов проверки есть ошибка. Можете помочь, сказав где ошибка (не могу найти сам)[image: Скрин из Академия Яндекса]

Мой код на python:

```
def max3(n, arr):
    max1 = 0
    max2 = 1
    max3 = 2

    t = 1
    while t:
        if ((arr[max1] <= arr[max2]) and (arr[max1] <= arr[max2]) and (arr[max1] <= arr[max2])):
            t = 0
            break
        if (arr[max1] > arr[max2]):
            max1, max2 = max2, max1
        if (arr[max2] > arr[max3]):
            max3, max2 = max2, max3

    min1 = max1
    min2 = max2

    for i in range(3, n):
        if arr[max3] <= arr[i]:
            max1 = max2
            max2 = max3
            max3 = i
        elif arr[max2] <= arr[i]:
            max1 = max2
            max2 = i
        elif arr[max1] <= arr[i]:
            max1 = i

        if (arr[min1] >= arr[i]):
            min2 = min1
            min1 = i
        elif (arr[min2] > arr[i]):
            min2 = i

    maxarr = arr[max1] * arr[max2] * arr[max3]
    minarr = arr[min1] * arr[min2] * arr[max3]

    if maxarr > minarr:
        print(maxarr)
    else:
        print(minarr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    k = int(input())
    arr1 = input()
    nums = list(map(int, arr1.split(' ')))
    max3(k, nums)
```

Comment: Несколько  вводов с неправильным ответом `[1, 1, -2, 1, 1, 0, -3, 1]  [-4, 1, -1, 0, -5, -4, -3, -5] [-4, 0, -4, -2, -1, -3, -1, -3] [-7, -2, -6, -1, -3, -1, -6, -3]`

Comment: @MBo, спасибо, так намного легче найти ошибку. Начну искать.

Comment: Нашел ошибку, спасибо. Ошибка в условии if, скопировал и забыл изменить
```
while t:
        if ((arr[max1] <= arr[max2]) and (arr[max1] <= arr[max2]) and (arr[max1] <= arr[max2])):
            t = 0
            break
        if (arr[max1] > arr[max2]):
            max1, max2 = max2, max1
        if (arr[max2] > arr[max3]):
            max3, max2 = max2, max3
```

Comment: Никак не надо менять статус вопроса, достаточно того, что вы ответ отметили принятым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм словами не описан, буду гадать. Можно предположить что после цикла `while` ожидается что значения возрастают: `arr[max1] <= arr[max2] <= arr[max3]`. Это ясно из анализа цикла`for`. Проверим:

```
def max3(n, arr):
    max1 = 0
    max2 = 1
    max3 = 2

    t = 1
    while t:
        if ((arr[max1] <= arr[max2]) and (arr[max1] <= arr[max2]) and (arr[max1] <= arr[max2])):
            t = 0
            break
        if (arr[max1] > arr[max2]):
            max1, max2 = max2, max1
        if (arr[max2] > arr[max3]):
            max3, max2 = max2, max3

    print(arr[max1], arr[max2], arr[max3])


max3(3, [10, 20, 30])
max3(3, [10, 30, 20])
max3(3, [20, 10, 30])
max3(3, [20, 30, 10])
max3(3, [30, 10, 20])
max3(3, [30, 20, 10])
```

> ```
> $ python test.py
> 10 20 30
> 10 30 20
> 10 20 30
> 20 30 10
> 10 20 30
> 10 20 30
> ```

В четырёх случаях сортировка удалась, в двух провалилась. Самый неприятный случай `20 30 10`. Давайте сделаем из него "плохой" пример: `20 30 10 15`. Неправильная сортировка приводит к тому что в первом `if` внутри `for` значения меняются так: было `20 30 10`, стало `30 10 15` (я напечатал не индексы а соответствующие значения). Произведение уменьшилось с 6000 до 4500.

Хорошие новости: главная идея верная. Надо подобрать три положительных побольше или одно положительное побольше и два отрицательных поменьше. Нужно уметь искать три максимума и два минимума.

Для поиска трёх максимумов будем поддерживать упорядоченный список из не более чем трёх элементов. Первоначально список пустой, новые элементы вставляются так чтобы порядок сохранялся. Если после вставки элементов больше трёх, первый (минимальный) удаляется:

```
def insert(a, v):
    a.append(v)
    for i in reversed(range(len(a) - 1)):
        if a[i] <= a[i + 1]:
            break
        a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]


def get_max3(a):
    max3 = []
    for v in a:
        insert(max3, v)
        if len(max3) > 3:
            max3.pop(0)
    return max3


def get_min2(a):
    min2 = []
    for v in a:
        insert(min2, v)
        if len(min2) > 2:
            min2.pop()
    return min2


def main():
    input() # skip n
    a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    max3 = get_max3(a)
    min2 = get_min2(a)
    print(max(
        max3[0] * max3[1] * max3[2],
        max3[2] * min2[0] * min2[1]
    ))


main()
```

**P.S.** `get_max3` и `get_min2` через `sorted`:

```
def get_max3(a):
    max3 = []
    for v in a:
        max3 = sorted(max3 + [v])[-3:]
    return max3


def get_min2(a):
    min2 = []
    for v in a:
        min2 = sorted(min2 + [v])[:2]
    return min2
```

**P.P.S.** Встроенный модуль [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) умеет делать всё из коробки - [heapq.nlargest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), [heapq.nsmallest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
import heapq


input() # skip n
a = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
max3 = heapq.nlargest(3, a)
min2 = heapq.nsmallest(2, a)
print(max(
    max3[0] * max3[1] * max3[2],
    max(max3) * min2[0] * min2[1]
))
```

Comment: Спасибо за замечания и помощь, в будущем буду описывать алгоритм словами